# Simple way to compare a character in a position in a line to rest of lines at same position (Perl)

Tags: perl, comparison, position, character

I have a file with a bunch of lines and want to compare to see if all the characters of a particular column match with the rest of the file in Perl. For example if I have a file:

```
abcdefg
avcddeg
acbdeeg
```

The file would read **a, d, g** as matches and return the position.

I was thinking about using a 2D array in perl to traverse and compare the entire file but it can get tedious. Does anyone have an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: From the way I read your question, there's no way to avoid checking each index at least once in the case of a matching index. So, what you really want is the best way to bail early on the non-matching lines?

Comment: This looked like a fun challenge for [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) to me, [so I made it into one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4665/find-columns-where-all-characters-are-the-same).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a clever (and fast) solution using bitwise ops.  It relies on the fact that `a & b & ... & z` equals `a | b | ... | z` if and only if all of `a`, `b`, ..., `z` are equal.

```
# read first line:
chomp( $_ = <> );
my $join = my $meet = $_;

# read other lines:
while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    $join |= $_;
    $meet &= $_;
}

# print matching columns:
foreach my $i ( 0 .. length($meet) - 1 ) {
    my $a = substr $join, $i, 1;
    my $b = substr $meet, $i, 1;
    print "$i: $a\n" if $a eq $b;
}
```

Test input:

```
abcdefg
avcddeg
acbdeeg
```

Output:

```
0: a
3: d
6: g
```

Ps. This solution works even if the lines have different lengths; no columns beyond the end of the shortest line will be considered as matching.

Comment: "a & b & ... & z equals a | b | ... | z if and only if all of a, b, ..., z are equal." Meaning a single digit of a, b, .., z, not that all of a is equal to all of b is equal to all of z?

Comment: The statement holds for any bitstrings.  Since my output loop compares the strings character-by-character, it produces a list of matching characters.  (Remember that using bitwise ops like `&` and `|` on strings just applies to operation to each bit of the strings in parallel -- that's why they're called "bitwise".)  I could've just as well used `vec` instead of `substr` to produce a list of matching bits (or nibbles or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to compare every index with its others to determine a full match, I'm not certain how you can make it less tedious. You can avoid building 2D arrays by utilizing substrings.

```
my @matchedIndexes;
my $pattern = "abcdefg";
INDEX:
for $index ( 0 .. ( length($pattern) - 1 ) ){
    for $line (@remainingLines){
        #if we find a nonmatch at the index, cut out.
        if ( !(substr($line, $index, 1) == substr($pattern, $index, 1) ){
            next INDEX;
        }
    }
    #if we made it here without cutting out, the whole set of lines matched.
    push @matchedIndexes, $index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise xor `^`. Xoring two strings leaves zeros in postitions where the strings are identical.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $previous;
my $first = 1;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $previous = $_ if $first;
    undef $first;
    my $in = $previous ^ $_;
    my $p;
    my @u = unpack 'c*', $in;
    $p .= $u[$_] ? ' ' : substr $previous, $_, 1 for 0 .. $#u;
    $previous = $p;
    last if $p =~ /^ +$/; # no more matches possible
}

print pos $previous, ": $1\n" while $_ = $previous =~ /(\S)/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not effective and memory hungry, but pretty readable and straightforward:

```
use strict;use warnings;

my $lead = <DATA>;
chomp $lead;
my $rest = do { local $/; <DATA> }; 

for (my $i = 0; $i < length $lead; $i++ ) {
    my $char = substr $lead, $i, 1; 
    next if $rest =~ /^.{$i}[^\Q$char\E]/m;
    print "$i:$char\n";
}


__DATA__
abcdefg
avcddeg
acbdeeg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the file line by line, marking array elements as `undef` when there's a line for which there's no common match:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $read,"<","input_file") or die $!;

my $first=1; #Flag to indicate whether or not we are on the first line.
my @characters=(); #Array for characters

while(my $line=<$read>)
{
  chomp($line);
  if($first)
  {
    @characters=split(//,$line);
    $first=0;
  }
  else
  {
    my @temp_arr=split(//,$line);

    foreach(0..$#characters)
    {
      $characters[$_]=undef unless $characters[$_] eq $temp_arr[$_];
    }
  }

  #If we do not have any characters in common, bail out!
  unless(scalar(grep{defined($_)}@characters))
  {
    print "Sorry, there are no characters in common positions within all rows of file input_file\n";
    exit(1);
  }
}

close($read);

print "Here are the common characters and positions:\n\n";

foreach(0..$#characters)
{
  print "" . ($_ + 1) . ": " . $characters[$_] . "\n" if defined($characters[$_]);
}
```

For the input  in your question, the output is:

```
Here are the common characters and positions:

1: a
4: d
7: g
```

Note that this code assumes that all of your lines are of the same length (or, at the very least, no line is longer than the first line).  If that's not the case, then you'll need to adjust the code accordingly.